# Dynamic sprites with Arraylist - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, awt

[GameCanvas](http://pastebin.com/zcFPbKZG)

AppleEnity - http://pastebin.com/ZVyL5fRm

Enity - paste bin.com/r4cqtr8B (cant post more than 2 links yet)

I have problem with adding new, dynamic sprites to my scene. Pressing E (with should spawn randomly an apple) gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at start.GameCanvas.dodaj(GameCanvas.java:65)
at start.GameCanvas.keyPressed(GameCanvas.java:149)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: GameCanvas.java:65...whats der on line 65???

Comment: You also need to share your 'AppleEnity' for us to propose any solution.

Comment: Added AppleEnity and Enity with extends AppleEnity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is obviously in this line:

```
jablka.add(new AppleEnity("resources/apple.png", random.nextInt(400), random.nextInt(400)));
```

...but it's not about `jablka` variable, but with this expression:

```
random.nextInt(400)
```

you never initialize `random` variable:

```
private Random random;
```

Replace the line above with:

```
private final Random random = new Random();
```

And you'll be fine. Or just use [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) object or [`RandomUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/RandomUtils.html).

Comment: @JakobekS: do you still have a problem with rendering? Please open another question and leave a link here as the problem you explained (NPE) is fixed.